# Is it possible to publish an idea in a paper without a proof of concept?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, publishability

I am currently a programmer and an engineering student in France, and I have a research idea which I would like to formally share with the scientific community.

The problem is that this idea is not a purely theoretical one, but one with practical implications. The idea itself is not extremely complex and its detailed explanation is not very long, but even a minimal implementation would take too long (I currently have to work and study at the same time) and would require hardware that I do not possess. Also, such a basic implementation would not be very useful, and would not prove the scalability.

I want to share my idea, so that perhaps someone somewhere can implement it and use it. In short, I'd like to contribute to the scientific community. Is it possible to formally publish a theoretical model of my idea along with a detailed explanation of its use-cases, advantages and limitations as a scientific article (like in arXiv, perhaps through my university) ?

Comment: **Seek advice from a professional in the field.** Whether what you have is publishable or not is something that is best determine by an expert; ask a professor in your school about it.

Answer (score 9):

What you can publish depends on the rules and judgement of the publisher. You can self-publish anything you like, using your own rules.

For [arXiv](https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit/index.html) there are a few additional rules. If you have the rights to register with them, normally granted to academics or those who are "endorsed" by an academic, then you need to pass their moderation process, which is weaker than a true review, intended to weed out cruft and crank posts. But arXiv is intended for preprints of things that will, at some point, see more formal publication. Moderation looks for things that would be reasonable to go through a formal review process, but doesn't actually provide it. No one attests to the actual validity of the ideas in a submission.

For established (reputable) publishers such as those of commercial enterprises and scientific/academic societies, a paper is evaluated by reviewers and accepted or not by one or more editors. But the standards for this are probably higher, in most cases, than for a speculative idea paper with little or no evidence.

It seems likely that you can publish at arXiv, but much less likely that a formal publisher would accept the paper. It isn't impossible, but the standards for novelty and significance are normally quite high. A professor at your institute can probably provide the required arXiv endorsement, if they are willing.

If you want more formal publication, then you have to satisfy the reviewers. I suspect that you need to do more to get to that point. But, an arXiv paper might "set a marker" for the future development of the ideas.